# Format input data with regex in AngularJS

Tags: regex, angularjs, dataformat

I have some data in the following format. With the use of regex I want to display only the first two tokens.

For example **AB.JKL**.MNO.XYZ => AB.JKL

```
AB.JKL.MNO.XYZ
KJ.KJLJ.KD.IUOI
KLJ.LK.LJ.JL.OLJ.JLL
```

Note: I am using AngularJS I can achieve this using Angularjs expression directly in the html but the html is a common template where other data is also being displayed I don't want to corrupt it. Therefore I want to apply regex on data in controller.

Comment: `"AB.JKL.MNO.XYZ".split('.', 2).join('.')` we need a benchmark battle :p

Comment: @hjpotter92 could you form a similar expression to select the last two tokens so that AB.JKL.MNO.XYZ => MNO.XYZ ?

Comment: @Kaizar I would simply go for `([^.]+\.[^.]+)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex-wise:**

If you want to grab a `<letters><dot><letters>` format, this regex will capture at the beginning:
`^([^.]+\.[^.]+)`

Same thing, but at the end of your string: 
`([^.]+\.[^.]+)$`

**Angular-wise**

I am not so familiar with angular, but from what I understand, you can create your own type of filters.

```html
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">
    first token: {{name | firstToken}} </br>
    last token: {{name | lastToken}}</br>
    any Regex: {{name | regex:"[^.]+$"}}</br>
</div>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('regex', function () {
    return function (input, regex) {
        if (!input) return '';
        var matches = input.match(regex);
        if (matches) return matches[0];
        return "";
    };
}).filter('firstToken', function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (!input) return '';
        var matches = input.match(/([^.]+.[^.]+)/);
        if (matches) return matches[0];
        return "";
    };
});

function Main($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'AB.JKL.MNO.XYZ';
}
```

Have fun, play with it: 
http://jsfiddle.net/lcoderre/WfuAh/97/

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up creating my own filter.